# Partition Equal Subset sum in Golang exceeding time limit

Tags: algorithm, go

I am running this program to solve partition sum problem using DP with memoization but this is exceeding time limit

```
Time Submitted         Status             Runtime  Memory  Language
08/30/2022 23:49    Time Limit Exceeded    N/A      N/A     golang
```

what I am missing:-
[Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/j-321wVToAE)

DP example function:-

```
func canPartition(nums []int) bool {
    // sum & divide by 2, mod should be 0
    sum := 0 
    fsum := 0
    
    if len(nums) > 0 {
        for i := range nums {
            sum = sum + nums[i]
        }
    } else {
        return false
    }
    
    if sum % 2 == 0 {
        fsum = sum/2 
    } else {
        return false
    }
    
    check := make(map[int]map[int]bool, 0)
    // initial subset of sum is 0
    check = map[int]map[int]bool{}
    return recurse(nums, 0, 0, fsum, check)
}

func recurse(nums []int, index, sum, total int, check map[int]map[int]bool) bool {
    if sum > total || index > len(nums)-1 {
        return false
    }

    if sum == total {
        return true
    }
    
    if _, ok := check[sum][index]; ok {
        return check[sum][index]
    }
    
    check[sum] = map[int]bool{index:recurse(nums, index+1, sum+nums[index], total, check) || recurse(nums, index+1, sum, total, check)}
    return check[sum][index]
}
```

Comment: Exceeding what limit?

Comment: @Adrian it is exceeding time limit. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This code have multiple issues:

1. when you use recursion, it makes all the memory to be allocated in a stack (which size is bounded), so if you will have many function call's, you'll eventually get a stack overflow error.
2. it looks like you are trying all possible combinations which takes O(n!). Modern CPU can handle about 10^9 operations per second, so if n > 13 you will count it forever.

It would be better to think about another solution. BUT this problem is NP full, and the best solution seems to be O(2^n) complexity, so you probably have too large testing set anyway.
Also it seems to be a good idea to reduce the same matching numbers (in pairs) as with this complexity even a small downgrade of n gives a nice exponential time win